Validating JSON data against my schema in C# using JsonSchema.Net
I'm evaluating the JsonSchema.Net and trying to figure out how to validate data during deserialization.
For reference, I am using a simple Person model, like this:
using Json.Schema.Generation;

public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; } // Middle name not required

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}

According to their docs, I should be able to use a ValidatingJsonConverter instance in the options like this:
using System.Text.Json;
using Json.Schema;
using Json.Schema.Serialization;

public void TestDeserialize()
{
    var json = """
    {
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "MiddleName": "Jones"
    }
    """;

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = { new ValidatingJsonConverter() } 
    };

    // According to their docs, this should throw an exception if validation fails
    var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(json, options);
}

However this does not cause an exception to be thrown as I would expect it to. I deliberately left out the required BirthDate on the json but in my test the data deserialized into an object with the first and last names filled out and a default value in the BirthDate property.
Alternatively, I tried this approach:
using Json.Schema;
using Json.Schema.Serialization;
using Json.Schema.Generation;

public void TestEvaluate()
{
    var json = """
    {
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "MiddleName": "Jones"
    }
    """;

    var schema = new JsonSchemaBuilder().FromType<Person>().Build();
    var results = schema.Evaluate(JsonDocument.Parse(json));
}

This approach shows a false value on the IsValid on the results object but there's no errors in the result to say what caused the failure. If I add the BirthDate field into the JSON, the IsValid property shows a true value.
I feel like I must be doing something wrong but I'm following what the docs say to do and I'm a bit lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

You can generate Json Schema based on your class, like this:
JsonSchema schema = new JsonSchemaGenerator()
    .Generate(typeof(Person));

Then you can use it for validation:
var result = person.IsValid(schema, out var errors);

errors will contain all errors.
EXAMPLE
Having such implementation:
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

JsonSchema schema = new JsonSchemaGenerator()
    .Generate(typeof(Person));

void Validate(JObject person)
{
    var result = person.IsValid(schema, out var errors);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    errors.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}

JObject validPerson = JObject.Parse(@"{
    'FirstName': 'Michal',
    'LastName': 'Turczyn'
}");

JObject invalidPerson = JObject.Parse(@"{
    'FirstName': 'Michal'
}");

Validate(validPerson);
Validate(invalidPerson);

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

This is the result:

True
False
Required properties are missing from object: LastName. Line 1, position 1.


This example does not use the library I'm trying to use.  Best I can tell JsonSchemaGenerator comes from Newtonsoft, which I'm trying to avoid taking a dependency upon that library in favor of relying on a System.Text.Json based ecosystem.

Those [Required] annotations on your Person class are coming from the Json.Schema.Generation package. This is for generating a JSON schema (the object that contains information which defines the structure of JSON). This object can then be serialized into JSON (how JSON schemas are usually stored and shared) or in your case, used in code to validate some JSON text e.g.
// Generate the json schema from an annotated class via reflection
var personSchema = new JsonSchemaBuilder()
    .FromType<Person>()
    .Build();

// The schema can be serialized as json (canonical json schema format)
var personSchemaAsJsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(personSchema);

// The schema can be used to validate json string
// Note this json string first needs to be parsed into a JsonNode object
var result = personSchema.Evaluate(JsonNode.Parse(json));

if (!result.IsValid)
{
    // The .IsValid property describes if the json string matches the schema
}

However, be aware that the process of generating schemas "on the fly" from model classes, and then using them to validate etc. is generally recommended against. It is better to create the schemas from a separate activity - whether that's manually generating the schemas, or it being as part of some automated build chain. As this helps separate the concerns of serialization from validation, keeping your classes clean. Separating the schema generation from its usage also allows for a proper review of the schema by others before it gets used in production. Code generation tools like this are a good starting point if you need to iterate fast, but consider carefully for production use.
With that said, if you wanted to define json schemas directly without sticking a bunch of annotations on your classes, you can by defining the following (based on your Person example):
public static class Schemas
{
    public static JsonSchema PersonSchema =
        new JsonSchemaBuilder()
            .Type(SchemaValueType.Object)
            .Properties(
                (nameof(Person.FirstName), new JsonSchemaBuilder()
                    .Type(SchemaValueType.String)
                ),
                (nameof(Person.MiddleName), new JsonSchemaBuilder()
                    .Type(SchemaValueType.String)
                ),
                (nameof(Person.LastName), new JsonSchemaBuilder()
                    .Type(SchemaValueType.String)
                ),
                (nameof(Person.BirthDate), new JsonSchemaBuilder()
                    .Type(SchemaValueType.String)
                )
            )
            .Required(nameof(Person.FirstName))
            .Required(nameof(Person.LastName))
            .Required(nameof(Person.BirthDate))
            .AdditionalProperties(false);
}


And then you would annotate your Person class with the schema
[JsonSchema(typeof(Schemas), nameof(Schemas.PersonSchema))]
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string BirthDate { get; set; }
}

Then desierializing with the ValidatingJsonConverter option will throw the exception you are looking for.
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new ValidatingJsonConverter() } 
};

// This now throws if the json doesn't match the schema
var person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(json, options);

